# SQL Statement and or between

Tags: sql, pdo

I get an syntax error with the following SQL PDO Statement, can you tell me where the mistake is?
Thank you!

```
SELECT * 
FROM events 
WHERE 
    (start_date BETWEEN '2013-01-14' AND '2013-01-20') 
    OR (start_date NOT < '2013-01-14' and end_date > '2013-01-20')
```

Comment: What's the error text?  my first guess would be date format is invalid.  my second one is that events might be a reserved word and may need to be escaped.  But the real znswer is your missing a ' after the 2nd date.

Comment: wouldn't start_date>='2013-01-14' be a better fit, right after the or?

Comment: As you suspect, "NOT <" is not valid syntax.

Comment: d'oh! I thought in PDO (which I don't know) it might be valid... missed out on that one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't put `NOT` in the middle of an expression, it goes before the expression:

```
NOT start_date < '2013-01-14'
```

Or use the complement to the `<` operator, which is `>=`:

```
start_date >= '2013-01-14'
```

(The exception in the usage of `NOT` is with the `IS NULL` operator, where both `NOT x IS NULL` and `x IS NOT NULL` works.)

Comment: Thank you. I never used the NOT expression before, thats why I made the mistake. Now it works. Thank you (ALL) very much! :)

Answer (score 4):

You're missing a ' after the date in the first section.

```
SELECT * FROM events WHERE (start_date BETWEEN '2013-01-14' AND '2013-01-20') OR (start_date NOT < '2013-01-14' and end_date > '2013-01-20')
```

Comment: yeah, you are correct. I must have lost it in the copy and paste process.. sorry and thank you! And I guess you are also correct with the start_date NOT < '2013-01-14' suspect, since I still get the error at this part..

Answer (score 1):

Your missing a tick after 2013-01-20

```
SELECT * FROM events 
WHERE 
(start_date BETWEEN '2013-01-14'  AND '2013-01-20')  
OR (start_date >= '2013-01-14' and end_date > '2013-01-20')
```

Comment: yeah, you are correct. I must have lost it in the copy and paste process.. sorry and thank you! but I still get the error, I guess it has something to do with the "NOT <" ..